# How to trigger an angular.js event after a file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, file

I have a list where users can click on 'list-items' and when they click on each row it triggers a file-chooser. heres the HTML..

```
              <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">

                      <!-- Pipe file through Service -->
                      <div style="padding-bottom:30px">
                        <div class="file" onClick="onFileButtonClicked()" ng-click="triggerEvent()">
                            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fastq-file" multiple />
                            <label class="file-button" for="fastq-file" >
                              <img src="img/upload.png" alt="add"> Upload FASTQ/FASTA File(s)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
```

heres the angular.js...

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.triggerEvent = function () {
        console.log("Changed");
    }
}
```

I already have a pure javascript 'on change' event that takes the file and pipes it into a service. What I need to do is have an angular.js event that is triggered after the file is selected.. so right now the angular 'ng-click' event gets triggered when the file-chooser is opened, not after the file is selected. How do I get an angular event to trigger after the file is selected and not when the file-chooser is opened.

ANSWER: I figured it out..

So in my javascript on change function I added this line of code..

```
 angular.element('#angular-controller').scope().myFunction();
```

Then in the HTML where I called the 'ng-controller="myController"' I put the id '#angular-controller'. So now when the javascript 'on change' function gets called it triggers the $scope.myFunction() thats in 'myController'.

Comment: Since I already have an 'onchange' function maybe I could call a function in my angular controller with pure javascript? Not sure if thats possible..

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking about emitting an event once the user hits "OK" to the file upload dialog?